# How to cite reset page numbers?

Tags: citation, mla

I'm trying to cite a "P.S." section of a book, *Green Grass Running Water* by Thomas King, but the page numbers just start again from 1 at the start of the P.S. section (i.e. the next page after 430 is 1). How would I cite from that section? Would it be just (King 15)? That would conflict with the 15th page of the actual novel.

The content is actually taken from a journal as well, so should I cite that instead even though it's from the back of a book?

Comment: So how is the context of the book cited in the journal?

Comment: In the front of the book (alongside copyright information and ISBN etc) it cites the journal as "Reading Notes taken from [standard MLA citation here]"